# TokenNotFoundError using getAssociatedTokenAddress() on MKRS NFT

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js, associated-token-account

I am working on a project that is pretty urgent and this error stays prominent when I try and fetch the Token Account of an MKRS NFT:[image]

All other NFTs work fine, so I'm not sure why this one doesn't.

Here is the suspected code fault:

```
const tokenAcc = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, this.publicKey);
```

I'm not sure why this is the only NFT that doesn't work.

[Link](https://solscan.io/token/8r7qv9byLTbcAD1P616KeEG5KqJD7LVnNuDCVXjUqVwG) to NFT on Solscan.

Comment: what is the value (pubkey) of this.publickey and mint

Comment: @WrathionTBP mint is the token mint address and this.publicKey is the user's public key

note: the mkrs NFT is frozen/staked but we're not sure what the exact problem is since other nfts that are frozen fetch fine (as shown in the "Mint:  ... Token Account: ..." log)

Comment: Have you tried making a getAssociatedAddress() call and checking that the token is actually in the correct token account it expects for the user? It's possible it might in a different account and not following the standard if the returned address is different.

Comment: @TonyBoyle I can't seem to find getAssociatedAddress() on the native solana sdk, only getAssociatedTokenAddress() (which is the source of the error) -- It throws a Token Not found error.

Comment: Can you please replace these screenshots of the error message with the text of the error message? This will make your question and the answers attached to it searchable in Google for others having the same trouble as you.

Comment: `TokenAccountNotFoundError` is not something that's thrown from `getAssociatedTokenAddress`, so that error is coming from somewhere else in your code. When you find where that's being thrown, update your question with the details so that someone can help you solve it!